# Skype is too humble

Tags: kde, skype

Is there a way to make skype for linux beta blink on new messages?

Under windows I have had a blinking tab for each contact that wrote me. But under KDE I only have one tab and it is only slightly highlighted. 
I use 2 monitors and always completely miss this.

Unfortunately I do not have sound available on my system.

I am running: Kubuntu 16.04 with KDE Backports enabled and use the official Skype PPA

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you on? On AskUbuntu, you usually should state your version.

Comment: Sorry. totally forgot.. x_x;

Comment: well which is it?

Comment: @tatsu Kubuntu 16.04, see OP's edit.

Comment: I know how you could do something more noticable on desktops like Budgie, Gnome, and Pantheon, but not on KDE